# How to restart at specific binlog position?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, events, mysqlbinlog

I'm using nodejs mysql-events to parse mysql db updates.
To avoid parsing all logs each time I relaunch my script, I want to use `binlogName` and `nextPosition` as read from [documentation](https://github.com/rodrigogs/zongji#zongji-class)

> filename  string  Begin reading events from this binlog file. If
>   specified together with position, will take precedence over
>   startAtEnd.
>
> position  integer Begin reading events from this position. Must be
>   included with filename.

The below code works like a charm:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const MySQLEvents = require('@rodrigogs/mysql-events'); 

// Connect to mysql instance
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'host',
    user: 'user',
    password: '*****'
});
const mysqlInstance = new MySQLEvents(connection, {
    startAtEnd: true
});

await mysqlInstance.start();
```

Values are valid and copied from vscode debugger.

```
mysql> show master status;
+------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| File       | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set |
+------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| bin.000015 | 34837697 |              |                  |                   |
+------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Once I change the mysqlInstance settings, it ignores it and start from first log.

```
const mysqlInstance = new MySQLEvents(connection, {
    binlogName: 'bin.000015',
    nextPosition: 18540004
});
```

Should I specify something else?